# Проектирование контакт листа Qt

Tags: c++, qt, design

Нужно написать контакт лист для мессенджера. Для этого пытаюсь правильно все спроектировать для удобной работы и простого расширения.

На данный момент имеется несколько моделей сущностей с представлений для них. Назовем их `User`, `Chat`, `Group` (у всех есть общий родитель `AbstractModel`) и `***View` для каждого из них.
Необходимо это красиво рисовать списком пока по некоторым критериям:

- Только группы
- Только контакты
- Переписка (чаты и контакты)

Знаю, что уже на этом этапе все плохо, но проект коммерческий и все переписать я не могу.

Так вот, на данный момент лучшее, что я придумал это сделать модель, унаследованную от `QAbstractListModel` и содержать в ней все элементы (`QVector<AbstractModel>`), эту модель привязать к `QListView` и создать `QSortFilterProxyModel`, которая как раз будет отвечать за отображение по критериям + сортировка.

Но в этом подходе наткнулся на одну очень весомую проблему, которую не могу решить уже на протяжении нескольких дней: у каждого элемента есть свое специфичное представление и я не знаю как его правильно установить т.к. `QListView` не умеет расширять строки по необходимости.

Самое забавное, что в `QListWidget` этих проблем в принципе нет, но привязать свои модели к нему нельзя...

Может я где-то не прав? Буду признателен, если укажите

Comment: "расширять строки по необходимости." - А QItemDelegate с этим не поможет?

Comment: @Madisson если использовать `QItemDelegate`, то придется использовать `createEditor`, а как установить виджет для представления(а не только для редактирования) таким образом я не знаю

Comment: На forum.qt.io мне подсказали одно интересное решение. Не совсем так как я хотел, но оставлю это здесь: https://forum.qt.io/topic/85193/how-to-resize-qlistview-row-to-index-widget-size/7